# Unit test own validation function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to testing and starting out writing a own validation method for my Angular app. But I cant figure it out how to test it with Karma. What is the right way to set a value and test it against my validation method?

I get following error
Property 'valid' does not exist on type 'void'.
Please be patient with me but I don't grasp why I get this error.

**The form**

```
this.carForm = this.fb.group({
    car: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
            id: car.id,
            properties: this.fb.group({
                color: 'blue',
                vinNumber: ['', ValidationService.isValidVinNumber]
            })
        })
    ]),
    registrationDate: '2011-11-12',
    howManyOwners: car.previousOwners,
    })
});
this.carForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
});
```

**The validation method**

```
static isValidVinNumber(formControl: FormControl) {
    if (formControl && formControl.value) {
        if (formControl.value.length !== 14) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**My test case not working**

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
}
........
it('should be possible to post empty vin number', () => {
    const iccNumber = component.carForm.get(['car', 0, 'properties', 'vinNumber']);
    expect(iccNumber.valid).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: your first test should be:          it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });  .........does that test pass?

Comment: Hello, I have that aswell:   it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

Comment: And it passes .